# Android webview tutorial not working

Tags: android, android-webview

This is the manifest file, I added the permission to go on Internet.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.a2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.a2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the xml file for creating the id webview.

Fragment XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.a2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.a2.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

And this is the code to get it running on my device

Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }*/
        WebView webPage = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webPage.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webPage.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a2/com.example.a2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: you have to extend `activity` to start activity

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.a2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <WebView

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview" />

</LinearLayout>
```

your problem is **android:id="@+id/webview"** ..you have to use **android:text="@+id/webview"**

please check this...i hope its solve your problem.

Comment: remove this line
 tools:context="com.example.a2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

to this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

EDIT:

and change `android:text` to `android:id`

Comment: Not working, says Unfortunately, a2 has stopped. I also tried adding HelloWebViewClient, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct this in your XML file :

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview" />
```

instead of

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@+id/webview" />
```

**Note** : Use `android:id` instead of `android:text`

**You are using fragment xml in your example.**

*fragment xml looks like* :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.a2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview" />
```

**You need to use activity xml.**

*activity xml looks like* :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.a2.MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this xml file your activity xml or fragment xml ?

Comment: Add the <Webview> code inside activity xml and not fragment xml.

Comment: Do you mind show me how you do that? When I did it, it gives errors. Says markup must be well-formed.

Comment: You can delete the fragment xml file and unwanted code related to fragment from your main activity java file and then just add the <webview> component inside activity mail xml file.Then clean your project and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Genius, You have to call fragment layout in your Activity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activity_main);
```

Because you did add the WebView component in your fragment layout. Here You had called empty layout, here you didn't add the WebView component. So did get the NullPointerException here.